# Notice: Undefined index body

Tags: php

I have sth like this:

```
<?php
    $body = $_GET["body"];
    if ($body=="")
    {
        include("includes/desktop.php");
    }
    else
    {
        if (is_file("includes/$body.php"))
        {
            include("includes/$body.php");
        }   
        else
        {
            include("includes/desktop.php");
        }        
    }                              
?>
```

How to make that this notice will disappear?
It happens only when $_GET["body"] is empty.

> Notice: Undefined index: body in C:\wamp\www\admin\index.php on line
>   106

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
$body = $_GET["body"];
```

To

```
$body = isset($_GET["body"]) ? $_GET["body"] : '';
```

You can find almost all symbols and operators in php [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Comment: It works for me. But truth telling I've never seen sth like this. Could you tell me what exactly mean "?" and ':' ?

Comment: @user3261158: Ternary operator

Comment: Ok. Thank's for help.

Comment: @user3261158: I have updated the answer with SO link. It is really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It is warning you that body is not sent via $_GET. You need to do something like this

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET["body"])) {
      $body = $_GET["body"];
      if ($body=="")
      {
          include("includes/desktop.php");
      }
      else
      {
          if (is_file("includes/$body.php"))
          {
              include("includes/$body.php");
          }   
          else
          {
              include("includes/desktop.php");
          }        
      }                              
  }
?>
```

Comment: There should be also ')' in second line. But It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because there is no index `body` in the superglobal `$_GET` array. In other words, you're not passing `$_GET['body']`.

Instead use:

```
if (isset($_GET['body']) && $_GET['body']) {
```

That checks for both the index and a meaningful (non-falsy) value.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if (!isset($_GET['body']) || empty($_GET['body'])) {
   include("includes/desktop.php");
} else {
    ...
}
```

http://www.php.net/isset

On a side note: You should *never* trust user input. Directly passing the body GET parameter to your include() call allows a malicious user to include files you never intended to load.